Preventing cookies from manually being edited
My application uses cookies. I checked developer tools, and noticed users can change the value. This is not secure, so I would like to know how I can create non-editable cookies.
I'm using Angular.

It is not possible to prevent users from manually changing cookie values. If your application is insecure as a result of this, something is wrong with how you've designed your application.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
